# How to access an autoloaded zsh function from a ruby script?

Tags: ruby, zsh

I have a function that I declare as autoloaded in my zshenv.  It works fine when I call it from the zsh prompt, or from a zsh script.  But when I try to call it from a Ruby script (using `` `my_zsh_autoloaded_function` ``), it fails.  I know Ruby is using zsh, and I know the zshenv is being sourced.  One workaround is to do `` `zsh -c "my_zsh_autoloaded_function"` ``.  Is there a way to give Ruby direct access?

Comment: How do you know that backticks are executing `zsh`?

Comment: @muistooshort `` puts `echo $SHELL` `` prints `/usr/local/bin/zsh`; also I have access to environment variables within the backticks that are defined in the `zshenv`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. That's not how Unix command execution works.

Zsh is essentially a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) just like `irb`.

In order to for Zsh to execute internal commands it has to do one of the following:

- Read the command from the REPL loop (STDIN)
- Execute the command using the `-c` switch, or..
- Run the command from a Zsh shell script file

None of those prerequisites are fulfilled when you just do `` `zsh_function` ``.

But you actually found (one of) the correct solutions already by using `zsh -c`.

But you were confused because you are looking at `$SHELL` and thinking you are running under `zsh`. `$SHELL` is not a reliable indicator of which shell is running:

```
> zsh
> echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/zsh
> sh
$ echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/zsh
$ bash
$ echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/zsh
$ SHELL=foo
$ bash
$ echo $SHELL
foo
```

So `SHELL` is simply copied from the originating environment into whatever new environment or shell you are spawning.

Now the final piece of the puzzle is hidden inside the Ruby source code, and also in the help file for [Kernel.exec](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec):

> **The standard shell always means "/bin/sh" on Unix-like systems**, same as ENV["RUBYSHELL"] (or ENV["COMSPEC"] on Windows NT series), and similar.

So no, `Kernel.system` or backticks on Unix will not run `zsh`. It will always run either the program directly (for example `/bin/ls`) or run `sh -c` in case of a bash command or a command which requires any other shell processing (like `ls *`).

It's easy to check too:

```
> zsh
> irb
> puts `ps xf; echo hello`
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
24122 ?        S      0:00 sshd: casper@pts/7
24127 pts/7    Ss     0:00  \_ -zsh
24686 pts/7    S      0:00      \_ zsh
24706 pts/7    Sl+    0:00          \_ irb
24710 pts/7    S+     0:00              \_ sh -c ps xf; echo hello
24712 pts/7    R+     0:00                  \_ ps xf
```

**Solution**

Either run using `zsh -c`, like you did, or create a separate Zsh shell script with the command and run that.

Comment: Thanks, for the thorough response-- very educational.  I do find one thing unclear though-- if Ruby WERE running zsh instead of /bin/sh, would simply calling the function in backticks work?  The first part of your response suggests that there is some reason that this would not work beyond the fact that the shell invoked with backticks is not zsh, but it's not clear to me what this reason is.  Put another way, is it possible for /bin/sh to execute "internal commands" (not quite sure what qualifies as an internal command) via the backticks?

Comment: @SeanMackesey That's a good question. And I guess I perhaps didn't word it the best way. You are right. As you can see Ruby is running `sh` also with the `-c` flag. So yes IF Ruby was using `zsh` instead of `sh` it would work, because the `-c` condition would be fulfilled in that case. That's the simple answer. It's a little bit more complicated than that in reality since Ruby has some internal logic to try and detect which backtick arguments are really internal `sh` commands and which are not (so that it knows when to trigger `-c`), but in theory yes it would work.

Comment: Ah, I see, makes good sense now.  Ruby parses the backticks input and routes certain commands through `sh -c` and in other cases calls programs directly.  Thanks again!

Comment: @SeanMackesey Correct. You can look at the relevant code here: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/1f828497d1e8df2b7b68ac2a093ab4439585d88a/process.c#L2033